# Can I use "verbally" in a written context?

Tags: adverbs, writing

Can I use "verbally" to refer to textual communication? For example, can I say "Verbally encourage this behavior" meaning "Encourage this behavior in writing"?

Comment: Good question! As @Henry says, you can't really use either of the obvious candidates *verbally* or *literally*. Effectively, we don't have an easy way to express this in writing apart from using *"in writing"* itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be unwise.

I suspect most people might understand *verbally* to mean *orally*, while those with a more classical education might understand *verbally* to mean *with words* from the Latin *verbum* as opposed to drawing pictures or giving a hug.

So if you mean "in writing", then use that phrase to avoid misunderstanding; *literally* may also be misunderstood.

This may contrast with other languages.  For example in French law, a *[procès-verbal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc%C3%A8s-verbal)* is a detailed written document.